# $_SESSION not accepting data

Tags: php

I am trying to set some data to `$_SESSION` but am unable to get anything into session for some strange reason. Here is my function that is suppose to put the items $name and $value into the session, but it seems to just get ignored, no values being put in.

Both of the values I have given output strings in the echo, so it should work fine...right?

I am not sure what other information I need to submit, but please let me know what is needed.

```
public static function put($name, $value) {
    echo $name . "<br>" . $value;
    return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
}
```

This is my init.php file. It is run at the start of every page. Took out the usernames and passwords obviously!

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    //csets variables for database connections
    'mysql' => array(
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => '',
        'host' => ''
    ),
    //remembering user when we login
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800 //Number of seconds in month
    ),
    //session informaton
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'
    )
);

//autoloads and require once all files in my classes folder
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once './functions/sanitize.php';

?>
```

Also my constructor function, which eventually calls put in my Session class.

```
    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');

        if(!$user) {
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);
                if($this->find($user)){
                    $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
                } else {
                    //logout
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->find($user);
        }
    }
```

Here is my login function where I call `put`.

```
public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
    $user = $this->find($username);
    if($user) {
        if($this->data()->password === substr(Hash::make($password), 0, 32)) {
            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
            var_dump($_SESSION);
            return true;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Finally my get method for session.

```
public static function get($name) {
            return $_SESSION[$name];    
        }
```

Also my method for exists..

```
public static function exists() {
        return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `session_start();`

Comment: I put session_start(); in my init.php file, which I 'include_once' on every single page. I am not sure if the session is actually starting though.

Comment: Add `echo session_id();` to your page, if you get an id then a session is starting, if not you need to find why.

Comment: Ok, got a long string of characters. guess it is starting...can you see where I am missing something to initiate the values in the code above?

Comment: @EternalHour you don't need `'`'s plus that would make a literal `$name` not a variable.

Comment: Call `var_dump($_SESSION)` after calling `put` and see if the values are being set. The problem might be in your `Session::exists` or `Session::get` methods which you haven't posted the code for.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION)` is outputting the following `array(3) { ["success"]=> string(28) "You registered successfully!" ["user"]=> string(2) "58" ["users"]=> string(2) "58" }`. You can see in the code above where I called it in the login function. Still no luck.

Comment: That looks like it should work. Can you `var_dump($_SESSION)` after `if(!$user) {`?

Comment: After `if($users)` seems to be fine. I then did it after `if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName))` but that seemed to not work.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution. The issue was with my exists method. I did not have the variable to setup the function.

This is what I had:

```
public static function exists() {
    return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
}
```

This is what I changed it too:

```
public static function exists($name) {
    return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: The evidence you've given shows you have a lot more problems. Why did it take you 45 minutes to discover something which would have been evident immediately if you had enabled error reporting?

Comment: For future reference, you can simplify the function a bit by changing it to `return isset($_SESSION[$name]);` rather than using a ternary operator.